# How to add incremental values to mysql database after sorting entries

Tags: mysql

ID | LastName | FirstName | Ordered

1 | Smith | John |

2 | Smith | Larry |

3 | Jones | Fred |

4 | Johnson | Todd |

Desired result: Update the Ordered field with incremental values in alphabetical order.

1 | Smith | John | 3

2 | Smith | Larry | 4

3 | Jones | Fred | 2

4 | Johnson | Todd | 1

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM MyDatabase ORDER by 
LastName,FirstName");

$N=0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
    {
    mysql_query("
    UPDATE MyDatabase
    SET Ordered = $N + 1
    WHERE ...");

   }
```

I know I need the WHERE but I can't seem to make any WHERE clauses work. I always end up with all the same numbers in the Ordered field. What would make this work as intended?

Comment: Well, I figured this out. Just needed to fetch the row number and compare it to the ID field.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you first need to get a total count of all rows in the result set (since you're storing from high to low you need to know the high). Then just decrement that value during the UPDATE / loop

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured this out to make it work. Just need to fetch the row and then compare it to the ID field as follows:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM MyDatabase ORDER by LastName, FirstName");

$N=1;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
{
$updateid = $row['ID'];
mysql_query("
UPDATE MyDatabase
SET Ordered = $N
WHERE ID='$updateid'");
$N++;
}
```